# Normal subgroup in center of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $3825$. Prove that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of order $17$ in $G$ then $H\leq Z(G)$.

In the link below, the solution basically says that the index of $C_{G}(H)$ must divide 225, and $Z(G)=17-1=16$ and so the index is $1, $ and $G=C_{G}(H).$ Why can't the index be 3, 5, or 15?

http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/if-a-subgroup-of-order-17-is-normal-in-a-group-of-order-3825-then-it-is-central/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $H$ is normal then $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation, inducing a homomorphism $G\to{\rm Aut}(H)$ with kernel $C_G(H)$. Therefore $G/C_G(H)\le{\rm Aut}(H)$, as is stated in the link. Thus, the index of $C_G(H)$ must divide $|{\rm Aut}(H)|=|U(17)|=\varphi(17)=16$ by Lagrange's theorem. Since $H$ is cyclic it is abelian and so $H\le C_G(H)$, hence the index of $C_G(H)$ divides the index of $H$, which is $3^25^2$. An integer dividing $16$ and $3^25^2$ must divide $\gcd(16,3^25^2)=1$, so the index is $1$ and $C_G(H)=G$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this-so in the third sentence, since $G/C_{G}(H)$ is isomorphic to $Aut(H)$ by first isomorphism theorem, and since the index of $C_{G}(H)$ is basically $|G/C_{G}(H)|$ by lagrange's theorem, it would divide $|$Aut$(H)$$|$ right?

Comment: @1mathboy1 We don't know that $G\to{\rm Aut}(H)$ is surjective, so all we can say is that $G/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a *subgroup* of ${\rm Aut}(H)$ (indeed by 1st iso thm). Besides that, yes, the index of $C_G(H)$ is the size of a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(H)$ so divides $|{\rm Aut}(H)|$ by Lagrange's.

Answer (score 2):

> THEOREMS USED-

- **Let $H  $ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Then $G $ acts by conjugation on $H$ as automorphisms of $H$.More specifically,the action of $G$ on $H$ by conjugation by $G$ is defined for each $g$$\in$$G$ by $$h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$$ $\forall  h\in H$

For each $g\in G$,conjugation by $g$ is an automorphism of $H$.The permutation representation afforded by this action is a homomorphism of $G$ into $Aut(H)$ with kernel $C_G(H)$.In particular, $G/C_G(H)$ is isomporphic to  a subgroup of $Aut(H)$.**

- **The automorphism group of a cyclic group of order n is isomorphic to U(n),an abelian group of order φ(n),Where φ is an Euler's function.**
- **Lagrange's theorem-If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$,then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$.**

> SOLUTION:

If  $H\unlhd G$,then $G$ acts by conjugation on $H$ as automorphism of H,with kernel $C_G(H)$
Hence,$G/C_G(H)\le{\rm Aut}(H)$.Since,H is of prime(17) order.So,$H$ is cyclic.So,$|{\rm Aut}(H)|=\varphi(17)=17-1=16$ .

Since,$G/C_G(H)\le{\rm Aut}(H)$,by Lagrange's theorem $|G/C_G(H)|$ divides $|{\rm Aut}(H)|$ this implies possible orders for $|G/C_G(H)|$ are $1,2,4,8.$-----(*)

Also,$C_G(H)\le{\rm G}$, again by Lagrange's theorem $|C_G(H)|$ divides $|G|$.

From (*), $|C_G(H)|$=$3825/2$ or $3825/4$ 0r $3825/8$
.But none of,$3825/2$ , $3825/4$ , $3825/8$$\in$$\mathbb Z$.Then only possibility left is $|C_G(H)|$=$3825/1$=$3825$=$|G|$ implying $G=C_G(H)$.

Since,$H$ is abelian ,$H\le{\rm C_G}(H)$ & $C_G(H)\le{\rm Z}(G)$.Thus,$H\le{\rm Z}(G)$

Comment: Hi. Isn't the inequality, $C_{G}(H) \leq Z(G)$. The reverse inequality is true in general. If your inequality were true, then $C_{G}(H) = Z(G)$. But this isn't true. Let $G = S_{3}$, and $H = \{ \sigma \},$ where $\sigma = (1 2 3)$. Now, $C_{G}(H) = \{1_{S_3}, \sigma  \}$ but $Z(G) = \{ 1_{S_3} \}$.

Comment: @JunaidAftab:$S_3$ is not abelian,while in the answer,it  is mentioned for abelian groups.

Comment: But why the possibility of index being 16 is not considered?